# Elasticsearch - M2.4 - Docker: Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, installation, elasticsearch, setup-upgrade

I have a docker with these env

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
9c46a3807d4f        dc_php-apache          "docker-php-entrypoi…"   21 hours ago        Up 21 hours         0.0.0.0:8050->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9050->443/tcp      dc_php-apache_1
2f3e7a799029        mariadb:10.3           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   21 hours ago        Up 21 hours         3306/tcp                                         dc_mariadb_1
6a40a702e37b        elasticsearch:7.8.1    "/tini -- /usr/local…"   21 hours ago        Up 21 hours         0.0.0.0:9200->9200/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9300->9300/tcp   dc_elasticsearch_1
```

Now when I run `bin/magento setup:upgrade`

I'm getting `Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster` 
I'm probably just missing a config somewhere but I want find where, activating or not the module `Magento_InventoryElasticsearch` doesn't seem to have any effect.

Thanks for your assistance !

Comment: your elastic search container and php-apache container need to be on the same docker network. Check whether you can ping dc_elasticsearch_1 from dc_php-apache_1. You should specify dc_elasticsearch_1 as the elasticsearch host in your config.

Comment: Actually i was just on the wrong database using a magento 2.4 docker when my database was configured for 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have --search-engine=elasticsearch7 in your install command. Also, check what happens if you enter the URL in the browser.